# How to determine and verify which RabbitMQ Queues are using SSL

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit

I am trying to demonstrate to others that my queue is using SSL, however from the RabbitMQ web management tools there seems to be no distinction over which queues are using SSL and which are not.

Using RabbitMQ management on localhost, I am able to see all my queues. I have set up SSL on port 5671 successfully using the troubleshooting from RabbitMQ website.

Using MassTransit I have configured my incoming bus to use localhost:5671/my_queue_name with a client certificate and all is working successfully - I just can't confirm to others that the queue is secure. If I get a message from the queue using the web management tools, I can read the (JSON) message in plain text. Any ideas how I can prove my messages are secure?

I've attempted using BusDriver to peek the queues but get nothing back (independent of whether is SSL or not).

Comment: I know this is really old, however, does this happen to be on a Windows environment? I ask because we are having some issues trying to connect to RabbitMq in MassTransit using SSL, and it appears we did everything correctly.

Answer (score 1):

SSL is used to secure connections, not to encrypt queue contents.

What SSL gives you is that communication from clients to RabbitMQ will be encrypted, so you could theoretically be sure that nobody tampered with your messages.

Also if you need to validate that the sender of the message is a particular user, you could use this RabbitMQ extension: http://www.rabbitmq.com/validated-user-id.html